# Is It Possible To Send Document/Pages/Blocks Invite Through Notion API

Tags: notion-api

It's similar to giving invite to the Integration but it should be done with Notion API. I can't find any docs on [Notion API](https://developer.notion.com).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but right now you cannot invite users to your pages with the API.